# Grails compiler mismatch

Tags: eclipse, grails

I am getting a message for when I start a new Grails project that `project level is 2.1 and workspace level is 2.0`.

When I go to `preferences>Groovy>compiler` it say the current version that I have is 2.0.7.

I have also tried right clicking on the project and then choosing `Groovy>fix compiler mismatch problems`.

I am using eclipse Kepler j2ee on a mac and using grails 2.3.3. How can I fix the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I think you should change your groovy compiler version to `2.1.5`

Currently i use Grails.`2.3.0` under `preference`->`grails`
and my groovy has been selected like this one `You are currently using Groovy Compiler 2.1.5`

There is a `Switch to Selection for Groovy Compilers` --but i suggest

1. Makes usre your groovy package has been insatlled or package is not corrupted and correct.
2. Change or install groovy compiler `2.1.5` that works fine with Grails 2.3.0 or Grails 2.3.3

and Make `Refresh Dependency` To your Project...

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project. Go to Properties.

[image]